# Import PyTorch 2.0.0 in colab

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to import PyTorch 2.0.0 in colab. This is what I am trying:

```
!pip install --upgrade torch torchvision torchaudio
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
```

This is the output:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: torch in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (0.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: torchaudio in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (1.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-cufft-cu11==10.9.0.58 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (10.9.0.58)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-cusparse-cu11==11.7.4.91 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (11.7.4.91)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-curand-cu11==10.2.10.91 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (10.2.10.91)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11==11.7.99 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (11.7.99)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.5.0.96 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (8.5.0.96)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (11.10.3.66)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11==11.7.101 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (11.7.101)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-nvtx-cu11==11.7.91 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (11.7.91)
Requirement already satisfied: triton==2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11==11.7.99 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (11.7.99)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-cusolver-cu11==11.4.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (11.4.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (3.10.7)
Requirement already satisfied: nvidia-nccl-cu11==2.14.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch) (2.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66->torch) (0.40.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66->torch) (67.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lit in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from triton==2.0.0->torch) (16.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cmake in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from triton==2.0.0->torch) (3.25.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torchvision) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow!=8.3.*,>=5.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torchvision) (8.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torchvision) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from jinja2->torch) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests->torchvision) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests->torchvision) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests->torchvision) (1.26.15)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests->torchvision) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from sympy->torch) (1.3.0)
1.13.1+cu116
```

I am not understanding why it is importing 1.13.1 version and not 2.0.0

I've tried to force python to import last version but it's not working

Comment: Did you use the 'force' parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the existing PyTorch installation:

```
[1] !pip uninstall -y torch torchvision torchaudio torchtext

Found existing installation: torch 1.13.1+cu116
Uninstalling torch-1.13.1+cu116:
  Successfully uninstalled torch-1.13.1+cu116
Found existing installation: torchvision 0.14.1+cu116
Uninstalling torchvision-0.14.1+cu116:
  Successfully uninstalled torchvision-0.14.1+cu116
Found existing installation: torchaudio 0.13.1+cu116
Uninstalling torchaudio-0.13.1+cu116:
  Successfully uninstalled torchaudio-0.13.1+cu116
Found existing installation: torchtext 0.14.1
Uninstalling torchtext-0.14.1:
  Successfully uninstalled torchtext-0.14.1
```

Then reinstall the desired version:

```
[2] !pip install torch==2.0.0 torchvision torchaudio torchtext

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting torch==2.0.0
  Downloading torch-2.0.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (619.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 619.9/619.9 MB 2.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting torchvision
  Downloading torchvision-0.15.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (6.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 6.0/6.0 MB 75.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting torchaudio
  Downloading torchaudio-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (4.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.4/4.4 MB 88.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting torchtext
  Downloading torchtext-0.15.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.0/2.0 MB 73.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch==2.0.0) (3.1.2)
Collecting nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66
  Downloading nvidia_cublas_cu11-11.10.3.66-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (317.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 317.1/317.1 MB 4.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.5.0.96
  Downloading nvidia_cudnn_cu11-8.5.0.96-2-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (557.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 557.1/557.1 MB 2.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting nvidia-curand-cu11==10.2.10.91
  Downloading nvidia_curand_cu11-10.2.10.91-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (54.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 54.6/54.6 MB 17.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11==11.7.99
  Downloading nvidia_cuda_runtime_cu11-11.7.99-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (849 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 849.3/849.3 KB 62.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting nvidia-cusolver-cu11==11.4.0.1
  Downloading nvidia_cusolver_cu11-11.4.0.1-2-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (102.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 102.6/102.6 MB 9.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting nvidia-cusparse-cu11==11.7.4.91
  Downloading nvidia_cusparse_cu11-11.7.4.91-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (173.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 173.2/173.2 MB 6.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11==11.7.101
  Downloading nvidia_cuda_cupti_cu11-11.7.101-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (11.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 11.8/11.8 MB 60.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting nvidia-cufft-cu11==10.9.0.58
  Downloading nvidia_cufft_cu11-10.9.0.58-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (168.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 168.4/168.4 MB 6.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting triton==2.0.0
  Downloading triton-2.0.0-1-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.whl (63.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 63.3/63.3 MB 11.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch==2.0.0) (3.0)
Collecting nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11==11.7.99
  Downloading nvidia_cuda_nvrtc_cu11-11.7.99-2-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (21.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 21.0/21.0 MB 64.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch==2.0.0) (1.11.1)
Collecting nvidia-nvtx-cu11==11.7.91
  Downloading nvidia_nvtx_cu11-11.7.91-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (98 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 98.6/98.6 KB 11.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting nvidia-nccl-cu11==2.14.3
  Downloading nvidia_nccl_cu11-2.14.3-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (177.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 177.1/177.1 MB 7.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch==2.0.0) (3.10.7)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch==2.0.0) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66->torch==2.0.0) (67.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66->torch==2.0.0) (0.40.0)
Collecting lit
  Downloading lit-16.0.0.tar.gz (144 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 145.0/145.0 KB 18.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: cmake in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from triton==2.0.0->torch==2.0.0) (3.25.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow!=8.3.*,>=5.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torchvision) (8.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torchvision) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torchvision) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torchtext) (4.65.0)
Collecting torchdata==0.6.0
  Downloading torchdata-0.6.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (4.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.6/4.6 MB 76.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.25 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torchdata==0.6.0->torchtext) (1.26.15)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from jinja2->torch==2.0.0) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests->torchvision) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests->torchvision) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests->torchvision) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from sympy->torch==2.0.0) (1.3.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: lit
  Building wheel for lit (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for lit: filename=lit-16.0.0-py3-none-any.whl size=93601 sha256=0ce98aa13f4f95e7a91ba8ad8aa75864c54cf40f4c24c1e52c853e6fa226ab32
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/c7/ee/80/1520ca86c3557f70e5504b802072f7fc3b0e2147f376b133ed
Successfully built lit
Installing collected packages: lit, nvidia-nvtx-cu11, nvidia-nccl-cu11, nvidia-cusparse-cu11, nvidia-curand-cu11, nvidia-cufft-cu11, nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11, nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11, nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11, nvidia-cublas-cu11, nvidia-cusolver-cu11, nvidia-cudnn-cu11, triton, torch, torchdata, torchvision, torchtext, torchaudio
Successfully installed lit-16.0.0 nvidia-cublas-cu11-11.10.3.66 nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11-11.7.101 nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11-11.7.99 nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11-11.7.99 nvidia-cudnn-cu11-8.5.0.96 nvidia-cufft-cu11-10.9.0.58 nvidia-curand-cu11-10.2.10.91 nvidia-cusolver-cu11-11.4.0.1 nvidia-cusparse-cu11-11.7.4.91 nvidia-nccl-cu11-2.14.3 nvidia-nvtx-cu11-11.7.91 torch-2.0.0 torchaudio-2.0.1 torchdata-0.6.0 torchtext-0.15.1 torchvision-0.15.1 triton-2.0.0
```

Confirm version:

```
[3] import torch
    print(torch.__version__)

2.0.0+cu117
```